# Maintain semantic Information in WPF FlowDocument

Tags: wpf

How can i add semantic information to e.g. Run and Paragraph Elements e.g. to mark s.th as headlines or code?

This tagging should also survive save and reload of documents in preferable RTF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to use The Tag Attribute and to Store The document in xaml instead of rtf